# Отсутствует перевод страницы справки о заблокированных сообщениях

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, заблокированные-вопросы

Собственно, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts). Я не помню, была ли эта страница раньше вообще или нет. Но сейчас перевод отсутствует. Имеет смысл разместить её оригинальный текст с разметкой в качестве вопроса и перевести общими усилиями. После чего встроить результат на сайт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Перевод выполнен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5539/176217) и внедрён на сайт. [Доступен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) в разделе справки.