# Перевод раздела справки «What is a locked post?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Ссылка на текущую версию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts
Ссылка на аналогичную запись на Stack Overflow на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts

---

Заголовок: «What is a locked post?»

A post which is "locked" cannot be modified in any way. Locking prevents...

- ...voting on the post (including close/reopen votes for questions)
- ...editing
- ...commenting
- ...answering (for questions)
- ...flagging (though "in need of moderator intervention" flags are still allowed, except in the case of Historical Significance locks - see below)

### Who can lock a post?

[Site moderators](/help/site-moderators) can apply specific types of locks to questions and answers.

Also, [the system itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will lock posts in certain situations:

- if the post is deleted via ["spam" or "abusive" flags](/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- if the post is migrated to another site.
- if the post was migrated *to* the current site, and then [rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).
- if a question was merged into another question, the answers will be moved and the source question will be locked.

### How long do posts stay locked?

This depends on why it was locked to begin with.

- When a moderator locks a post they're required to select how long the lock should remain in place. The options are: 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week, permanent. At the end of this time, the system will automatically unlock it.
- When the system locks a post it stays locked indefinitely - only a moderator can unlock it.

A moderator can manually unlock a locked post at any time if they deem it necessary.

### When should a post be locked?

As a general rule, *temporary* locks should be used whenever modifications to a post are causing serious problems on the site. For example:

- [Edit wars](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/)
- Extended bickering in comments (but see: [a guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments))
- A controversial post that is under discussion on meta

*Permanent* locks should almost never be used, with the exception of those imposed by the system itself. There are two exceptions:

1. An extremely popular question which is now considered inappropriate for the site may be locked for "Historical Significance": this alters the appearance of the question, automatically locks all *answers* as well, and disables flagging completely. This lock should be reserved for cases where a cherished cultural artifact would otherwise be deleted; **do not** use it for any other purpose.
2. A "wiki" is a question whose answers [can be edited by low-reputation users](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), attributed to multiple authors, and do not grant reputation to the original author. They're occasionally useful in cases where information *must* be compiled by multiple authors (for example, a list of resources or documentation for the site itself); in these cases, locking the question both prevents it from being closed and prevents further answers from being added.

#### See also:

- [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) on Meta Stack Exchange
- [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) on Meta Stack Exchange
- [Advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: Не пора ли уже запулить на сайт?

Comment: @alexolut Обычно мы ждем минимум одну неделю.

Comment: а чего тут ждать? Улучшения перевода? Что хорошего может произойти с этим переведенным текстом за неделю?

Comment: Вот если бы я тут ничего не написал, то и улучшений бы не было :) сто пудов!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Что такое заблокированное сообщение

Заблокированное сообщение нельзя изменить. Блокировка предотвращает:

- голосование (в том числе за закрытие и повторное открытие вопросов);
- редактирование;
- комментирование;
- публикацию ответов (для вопросов);
- использование тревог (точнее, тревога «требуется вмешательство модератора» возможна, за исключением случая исторической блокировки, описанной ниже).

### Кто может заблокировать сообщение?

[Модераторы сайта](/help/site-moderators) могут накладывать различные варианты блокировок на вопросы и ответы.

Также [сама система](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) может блокировать сообщения в следующих случаях:

- Если сообщение удалено через [тревоги о спаме или об оскорблении](/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- Если сообщение перенесено на другой сайт сети.
- Если сообщение перенесено на *этот* сайт, [но перенос отклонен](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).
- Если вопрос был объединён с другим, то ответы будут перемещены в целевой, а исходный будет заблокирован.

### Как долго сообщение остаётся заблокированным?

Это зависит от причины блокировки.

- Если сообщение блокируется модератором, он обязан выбрать время блокировки: час, день, неделя или бесконечность. Когда это время проходит, сообщение автоматически разблокируется.
- Если сообщение блокируется системой, то блокировка перманентная. Только модератор может снять блокировку.

Модератор может вручную разблокировать любое сообщение, если посчитает это нужным.

### В каких случаях сообщения должны блокироваться?

В общем случае *временные* блокировки должны использоваться тогда, когда постоянные изменения сообщения вызывают проблемы, например, в случаях:

- [войн правок](//stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/);
- активных бессмысленных споров в комментариях (пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [инструкцию по модерированию комментариев](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments));
- обсуждения спорного вопроса на Мете.

Практически во всех случаях стоит избегать *постоянных* блокировок, за исключением тех, которые ставятся самой системой. Существует два исключения:

1. Если очень популярный вопрос стал считаться неподходящим для сайта, он может быть заблокирован как *исторически значимый*. В таком случае изменится отображение вопроса, автоматически заблокируются все *ответы* на этот вопрос, а использование тревог будет полностью запрещено. Эта блокировка должна использоваться только в тех случаях, когда важному культурному артефакту угрожает удаление. **Не применяйте** её в других целях.
2. Общий вопрос – вопрос, ответы на который [могут редактироваться участниками с низкой репутацией](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), а сам вопрос может принадлежать нескольким авторам и не приносит репутацию никому из них. Это очень полезно в случаях, когда информация *должна* быть собрана воедино несколькими участниками (например, списки материалов, либо документация для самого сайта). В этих случаях блокировка вопроса одновременно защищает его от закрытия и от создания новых ответов.

#### Дополнительные ссылки:

- [Что означает статус сообщения «заблокировано»?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3293/)
- [Что собой представляет и для чего используется блокировка «историческое значение»?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2480/)
- [Как выполнять поиск?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, о! переводы нашлись!

Answer (score 3):

Комментарии к ответу **Qwertiy** от 28 июня, 21:33

> **Что такое заблокированное сообщение**
>
> Заблокированное сообщение нельзя изменить. Блокировка предотвращает:

Заголовок не соответствует тексту. Первое предложение предлагаю изменить до *Заблокированное сообщение - это сообщение, которое нельзя изменить.*, а второе - начать с новой строки.

> Также сама система может блокировать сообщения в следующих случаях:
>
> ...
>
> - если вопрос был объединён с другим, то ответы будут перемещены в целевой, а исходный будет заблокирован.

Текст не соответствует перечислению, предлагаю *то ответы* заменить на *при этом ответы*.

> Если сообщение блокируется модератором, он обязан выбрать время блокировки: час, день, неделя или бесконечность. Когда это время проходит, сообщение автоматически разблокируется.

Когда проходит бесконечность? сомнительная конструкция. Предлагаю заменить слово *бесконечность* на *без ограничения срока*, а конструкцию *Когда это время проходит,* на *По истечении времени блокировки*.

> Модератор может вручную разблокировать сообщение, если посчитает это нужным.

Считаю, что правильнее не просто *разблокировать сообщение*, а *разблокировать любое сообщение*.

PS. Текст вообще производит странное впечатление. Начинается как FAQ для пользователя, а заканчивается как инструкция для модератора.

Comment: 1. А определение _"Заблокированное сообщение - это сообщение, которое нельзя изменить."_ не соответствует действительности. То, что сообщение нельзя изменить, - это лишь одна сторона блокировки, но далеко не единственная. 2. Вообще связное предложение не получается с использованием "при этом". Можно предложение полностью? 3. А мне бесконечность нравится - она состоит из одного слова, как и остальное. 4. Согласен. 5. Оно и в оригинале такое :)

Comment: @Qwertiy 1) Тогда, вероятно, надо описывать все стороны. Или наоборот. Или вставить оговорку типа "в первую очередь"... 2) Откорректировал цитату. 3-5) Ок.

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, если вы согласные с какими–либо комментариями, внесите их в ваш ответ, чтобы получить целостный перевод!

Comment: 2. Я имел в виду предлагаемый вариант...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, готово.

Comment: @Qwertiy Огромное спасибо! Если особых возражений не будет, думаю, сегодня в конце дня можно будет обновить справку.